# create a symfony database with xampp

Tags: symfony, xampp

here is the error I get when I use php bin / console doctrine: database: create
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFlWj.png)

Answer (score 0):

You should use mysql not postgresql

```
DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
#DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```